# How do I make my character jump in every direction?

Tags: c#, unity, scripting

My character can only jump when he is grounded, but he can only grounded in one direction
I want him to jump in every direction, can anyone help?

**CAN JUMP :**

[image]

**CAN'T JUMP :**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
 using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player: MonoBehaviour {

public float maxspeed = 10f;
bool facingRight = true;

Animator anim;

bool grounded = false;
public Transform groundCheck;
float groundRadius = 0.2f;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;
public Vector2 jumpDirection = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
public float jumpFocre = 500f;

bool doubleJump = false;

void Start ()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}

void FixedUpdate () {
    grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
    anim.SetBool ("Ground", grounded);

    if (grounded)
        doubleJump = false;

    float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs (move));

    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(move * maxspeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
}
void Update()
{
    if((!doubleJump) && Input.GetKeyDown ("up"))
    {
        anim.SetBool("Ground", false);
        float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        jumpDirection.x = move;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpDirection.normalized * jumpFocre);

        if(!doubleJump && !grounded)
            doubleJump = true;
    }


}

void Flip()
{
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;    
}
}
```

Comment: Why are there four 'directions'? And shouldn't the vector representing up stay the same? I'm not really familiar with Unity, but from the pictures it looks like the character is being rotated, rather than flipped (which could be causing the collision issue).

Comment: Have you watched the [2D Character Controllers](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/2d-controllers) video? In it they provide step by step details on how a similar controller is built.  It explains why they used `groundCheck`/`groundRadius` and `OverlapCircle()` to determine when grounded and IIRC briefly discuss alternatives.

Comment: You may use two game objects to achieve this. One would be your character, the other would be the ground check. Character should rotate, ground check should not. Ground check object should follow the character, you can achieve this by using a script and setting the transform.position in Update. The other option is to have the ground check as a parent of the character. Then it will not rotate, when the character rotates.

Answer (score 2):

Your `groundCheck` `Transform` is a child of the player and rotates around the player when the player spins.

The `groundCheck`'s primary function is to provide a position to use when calling `OverlapCircle()`.

This means it could be replaced as follows:

```
public Vector3 groundCheckOffset = new Vector3(0f, -1f, 0f); // one unit down
// ...
grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(transform.position + groundCheckOffset, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
```

This will allow a ground check that travels with, but does not rotate around, the player.

Note that the actual value of `groundCheckOffset` will need to be modified to suit the size of your player.