# How do I make Ground Check stop rotating with the character when it rotate?

Tags: unity, c#

How do I make my character routice without Ground Check rotating with it, but still follow my character?

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player: MonoBehaviour {

public float maxspeed = 10f;
bool facingRight = true;

Animator anim;

bool grounded = false;
public Transform groundCheck;
float groundRadius = 0.2f;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;
public Vector2 jumpDirection = new Vector2(1f, 1f);
public float jumpFocre = 500f;
bool doubleJump = false;


void Start ()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}

void FixedUpdate () {
    grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
    anim.SetBool ("Ground", grounded);

    if (grounded)
        doubleJump = false;

    float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs (move));

    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(move * maxspeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
}
void Update()
{
    if((!doubleJump) && Input.GetKeyDown ("up"))
    {
        anim.SetBool("Ground", false);
        float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        jumpDirection.x = move;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpDirection.normalized * jumpFocre);

        if(!doubleJump && !grounded)
            doubleJump = true;
    }


}

void Flip()
{
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;    
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try [this suggestion](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/99202/how-do-i-make-my-character-jump-in-every-direction/99204#99204)?  How did it work out?  If it wasn't satisfactory how did fail to meet your requirements?  There are a couple of approaches one can take with issue and people can provide better assistance if they know what you have tried already and why it was not satisfactory.

Comment: I tried, but it keep poping up this :Assets/code/Player.cs(27,62): error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: `UnityEngine.Vector2.operator -(UnityEngine.Vector2, UnityEngine.Vector2)' and `UnityEngine.Vector3.operator -(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3)'

Comment: No problem. I have modified the code in that answer to clear up this error.

Comment: He jump fly up to the sky